# Plot multiple confusion matrices with plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, seaborn

I am using `plot_confusion_matrix` from `sklearn.metrics`. I want to represent those confusion matrices next to each other like subplots, how could I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's use the good'ol iris dataset to reproduce this, and fit several classifiers to plot their respective confusion matrices with [`plot_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target
```

Set up -

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
classifiers = [LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'), 
               AdaBoostClassifier(),
               GradientBoostingClassifier(), 
               SVC()]
for cls in classifiers:
    cls.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So the way you could compare all matrices at simple sight, is by creating a set of subplots with [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). Then iterate both over the axes objects and the trained classifiers (`plot_confusion_matrix` expects the as input) and plot the individual confusion matrices:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15,10))

for cls, ax in zip(classifiers, axes.flatten()):
    plot_confusion_matrix(cls, 
                          X_test, 
                          y_test, 
                          ax=ax, 
                          cmap='Blues',
                         display_labels=data.target_names)
    ax.title.set_text(type(cls).__name__)
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Function `plot_confusion_matrix` is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Use one of the class methods: [`ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator) or [`ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator).

Answer (score 1):

[if your desired output is that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61MZh.png) This is my way to see multiple confusion matrices (confusion_matrix) side by side  with ConfusionMatrixDisplay.

note: paste your own test and train data names in `metrics.confusion_matrix()` function.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].set_title("test")
ax[1].set_title("train")

metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(
    confusion_matrix=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred), 
    display_labels=[False, True]).plot(ax=ax[0])

metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(
    confusion_matrix=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred), 
    display_labels=[False, True]).plot(ax=ax[1])
```