# Train multiple classifiers and compare metrics

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, machine-learning

I want to calculate different classifiers in one run and transfer the results to a Pandas data frame.

```
# Lets create some test data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string 
import random
integers = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50, 1)), columns=list('I'))
strings = pd.DataFrame([random.choice('ab') for _ in range(50)], columns=list('S'))
df2 = pd.concat([strings,integers], axis=1)
df2.head()
    S   I
0   a   5
1   a   31
2   b   84
3   a   79
4   b   92


# Train - Test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df2[["I"]].values
y = df2["S"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

#Load libraries
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


#Classifiers 
classifiers = [
KNeighborsClassifier(30),
DecisionTreeClassifier(),
RandomForestClassifier(),
AdaBoostClassifier(),
LogisticRegression()]


n_range = list(range(1, 10))
RandomForestClf = []
data_frame = []

for n in n_range:
#    name = clf.__class__.__name__
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5, scoring="accuracy")
RandomForestClf.append(scores.mean())
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({"Random Forest": RandomForestClf})
```

I couldn't get the various classifiers to go through the for loop.

How do I set up the for loop so that each classifier is run through and then the prediction is transferred to a panda data frame?

My current for loop only works if the model is mentioned in the code.

I'm new to Python sry.

I appriciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the dataframe outside the for loop, and then just assign to it looking up the classifiers name checking the `type` of the object:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


#Classifiers 
classifiers = [KNeighborsClassifier(30),
                DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                RandomForestClassifier(),
                AdaBoostClassifier(),
                LogisticRegression()]

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

k = 5
preds = pd.DataFrame(index=[*range(k)])

for cls in classifiers:
    scores = cross_val_score(cls, X, y, cv=k, scoring="accuracy")
    preds[type(cls).__name__] = scores
```

In this case, you'd get:

```
print(preds)
   KNeighborsClassifier  DecisionTreeClassifier  RandomForestClassifier  \
0              0.900000                0.966667                0.966667   
1              0.966667                0.966667                0.966667   
2              0.933333                0.900000                0.933333   
3              0.900000                0.966667                0.966667   
4              1.000000                1.000000                1.000000   

   AdaBoostClassifier  LogisticRegression  
0            0.966667            0.966667  
1            0.933333            1.000000  
2            0.900000            0.933333  
3            0.933333            0.966667  
4            1.000000            1.000000
```

Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61016507/9698684) plotting multiple confusion matrices from a list of classifiers, in case you might find that useful too.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution! Unfortunately this code only iterates once through the loop. 
I would like to have several scores per, so that I can display the history of the n_estimators.
n_range = list(range(1, 10))

Comment: You mean all scores in the cross validation? @Skruff

Comment: Yes, exactly! So I can plot a diagram with the course of the estimators. @yatu

Comment: Updsted - Let me know if I understood correctly @Skruff

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! 
Many, many thanks! @yatu
Great community

Comment: Is it also possible to change the "n_estimators" per model in the same loop? I tried that with: 
n_range = list(range(1, 70))
for n in n_range:
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n) @yatu